# Best practices for usage of PHP’s Magic Constants

Tags: php, magic-constants

What are the best practices for usage of PHP’s Magic Constants, such as `__LINE__` , `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__`, `__CLASS__` and `__METHOD__`?

For example I use `__LINE__`  and `__CLASS__` to locate the SQL Error like this :

```
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die("Error SQL line ".__LINE__ ." class ".__CLASS__." : ".mysql_error());
```

Is this an acceptable practice?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "best usage"? The best usage is using them when they're needed, aren't they? :)

Comment: @Amirouche Douda, happy to help.  :-D

Comment: @jasonbar & Pekka: Question edited

Comment: I have no idea, but I realized that I don't use these often enough. Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practice you show has two shortcomings:

- You are not showing the file the error occurs in - you'd have to have a *very* strict file structure that maps classes to files 1:1 for this to be useful
- `__CLASS__` will show you the wrong result if the error occurs in an inherited class. Use `get_class($this)` to get the actual current class.

Other than that, using these constants is perfectly acceptable. Note that

- `__FUNCTION__` and `__CLASS__` were added in PHP 4.3
- `__METHOD__` is available since PHP 5.0.0
- `__DIR__` and  `__NAMESPACE__` are available since PHP 5.3.

[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Correction: `__DIR__` was added in PHP 5.3 not 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose for these constants is debugging and logging. This is exactly what you are doing.

`__FILE__` can also be used for relative file paths (e.g. `dirname(__FILE__)`).

Comment: Since PHP 5.3 there is `__DIR__` magic constant which is equal to `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 1):

The only advice I can give is that not all magic constants are defined.  So, when in doubt, use `if(defined('__MAGIC_CONSTANT__'))`

Comment: Some magic constants are undefined if you're using less the PHP5